# The most fancy way to write 2D array

Tags: arrays, typewriter

I have something like

[image]

What's the best way to do it? I tried this method but it doesn't work.

```
\begin{array}{r}[[0.86455156], \\ [-0.82104237], \\ [4.12186079]]\end{array}
```

Getting,

[image]

Comment: Is this code in math mode?

Comment: Yes, it's in math mode, I added the result in the answer

Comment: The error come from the fact that, in an array,\\ can take an optional argument. Replace it with `\\{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

This solution works in both text mode and math mode.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\ttfamily}r @{}}
  [[ 0.86455156], \\ \relax
   [-0.82104237], \\ \relax
   [ 4.12186079]]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```